# Variable modification within a useless condition

Tags: c, variables

Does this code have well-defined behavior if `foo == 13` is false?

```
if (foo == 13 && ++bar > 42)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes: google for "short circuit evaluation"

Comment: It is well defined, but when people have to ask how it works, it is not very *good* code. I would avoid using this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. If the first condition is false, the second will never be evaluated.

See [Avoiding the execution of second expression's side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Avoiding_the_execution_of_second_expression.27s_side_effects).